# Refresh Portlet in pop-up Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I have quick question regarding refreshing a portlet which was called from within another portlet.

I am calling a child-portlet in a parent-portlet like this

```
 `<liferay-portlet:renderURL portletName="<%= portletID %>"var="testPortletURL"  windowState="<%=windowMode%>"/>`
```

and open it in a pop up using the liferay.util

```
            var url = '<%= testPortletURL %>';

            Liferay.Util.openWindow({

                dialog: {   
                    destroyOnHide: true,
                    centered: true,
                    height: 600,
                    modal: true,
                    width: 750
                    },

                id: '<portlet:namespace/>testPortlet',
                title: 'Test',
                uri: url

            });
```

The child-portlet has a few forms and depending on the users action it might have to be refreshed. I am refreshing the portlet like this:

```
Liferay.provide(window, 'doRefresh', function() { 
    console.log('<%=themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getId()%>');
    var tmp = "#p_p_id_"+"<%= themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getId() %>"+"_";
    Liferay.Portlet.refresh(tmp);
},
['aui-base']
);
```

This works fine if the portlet is used by itself as a standalone and not called from another portlet. However, when the portlet is called from within another portlet the refresh action will not work and the following message is displayed.

> You do not have the roles required to access this portlet.

Does anyone know how I can safely refresh the portlet inside the dialog window, without getting this error?

Kind regards,
John